# VBA - Make chart B appear when series 1 of chart A is selected

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a chart with 14 series. Likewise I have 14 charts that are associated with each of these series. I am trying to create a macro that can be called when a particular series is selected. When the series is selected the macro makes the corresponding chart appear which gives the user more detailed data.

This is what I have come up with so far (Bear with me I am a weak programmer). Please let me know if I am on he right track and if not please give me some direction. this code currently gives me an error message "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Thanks!

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim Series6 As Object
Set Series6 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(6)

   If Series6.Select Then
   Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Visible = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: do you have all charts placed in one sheet? what if you try something like this: `Sheets("Quality Reporting").Chartobjects("Chart 7").Visible = true` but put proper name in parenthesis.

Comment: Yes they are all on the same page. But, I still get the same error.

Comment: did you put appropriate chart name within quotation marks?

Comment: Yes but it does not work. I am able to unhide the chart with part of the above code but I cannot figure out how to do this when a particular data point on the chart is selected. I wonder if this is even possible?

Comment: I've edited the original code that I posted. I am now working in a test file. The above still produces an error but I believe I am closer to doing what I want it to. Please chime in if you have any input.

Comment: Okay I have edited the above code yet again. This is starting to work. When I run this code, as long as I have chart 1 activated, it will select data point 6 which triggers chart 2 to appear. However, if the chart is not active then I receive an error message. Ideally I would like this action to be performed by just clicking the data point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create **Chart Events** to handle this type of thing

Assumptions:

- Charts are on `Sheet1`
- Master chart is named `Chart 1`
- Detail charts are named after the series number +1 (eg `Series 1` relates to `Chart 2`)

To set up chart events follow these steps

1. Create a Class Module named `EventClassModule`
2. Add code to this module

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public WithEvents myChartClass As Chart

   Private Sub myChartClass_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)
       Dim ChartName As String
       Dim i As Long
       If ElementID = 3 And Arg1 = 1 Then ' 3 indicates a Series
           ChartName = "Chart " & Arg2 + 1 ' Arg1 is the series number
           With Worksheets("Sheet1")
               ' Hide all sub charts
               For i = 2 To .ChartObjects.Count
                   .ChartObjects(i).Visible = False
               Next
               ' Show the required chart
               .ChartObjects(ChartName).Visible = True
           End With
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
3. Initialise the class module (best done as workbook open event: put this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module)

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Dim myClassModule As New EventClassModule

   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Set myClassModule.myChartClass = _
           Sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
   End Sub
   ```

Now, when a series on `Chart 1` is selected, the related detail chart is shown, and the others are hidden

Useful links
[MSDN Chart Object Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb211346%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
[MSDN Chart Select Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb242007%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks! This appears to be exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have another question...If I want to have just one series but I want the same functionality (corresponding charts appear when clicked) for the individual data points how would I go about accomplishing that. I know that ElementID = 3 is referring to the series and that Arg2 refers to the data point but I am unsure on how to translate that into workable code.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want to achieve: can you specify the relationship between the Series and Point numbers clicked and what you want to make visible?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. What I would like to achieve is when data point 1 of series 1 is clicked then chart 2 appears, when  data point 2 of series 1 is clicked chart 3 appears etc. I hope that is a bit clearer. In my original post I misstated that I wanted the hidden charts to appear when the different series were selected. What I meant to say in stead of series was data point.

Comment: Updated post to reflect latest request

Comment: Wow, I was so close. I had {If ElementID = 3 And Arg1 Then}. Thank you very much!